# Proof of the convergence of the Rayleigh-Ritz Method

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, operator-theory

In this article [The convergence of the Rayleigh-Ritz Method in quantum chemistry](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00548026) by Bruno Klahn & Werner A. Bingel they have at page 11

Let $H_B$ be that Hilbert space which can be obtained as the closure of $D_B$ with the $B$-norm
$$
\|f\|_B=(f, B f)^{1 / 2} .
$$
Where $B$ is a positive operator

> **Theorem 1**
> *Let the basis $\left\{\Phi_m\right\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ be complete in $H_B$ (i.e. relative to the $B$-norm). Then the rayleigh ritz method for the positive definite operator $B$ converges in this basis to the lowest exact eigenvalue $E_0$.*

> The main argument in the proof of Theorem 1 is as follows: If $u^{(M)}$ is any variation function from the linear space $D_M$ spanned by $\left\{\Phi_m\right\}_{m=1}^M$, the difference between the appropriate expectation value and the exact $i$ th eigenvalue of $B$ is given by
> $$
> \left(u^{(M)}, B u^{(M)}\right)-E_i \leqslant 2 E_i \beta^{-1 / 2}\left\|u^{(M)}-u_i\right\|_B+\left\|u^{(M)}-u_i\right\|_B^2 . \tag 1
> $$
> This equation holds in particular in the case $u^{(M)}=u_i^{(M)}$, i.e. if $u^{(M)}$ is the Ritz function. The Ritz eigenvalues can be characterized by
> $$
> E_i^{(M)}=\min _{u^{(M)} \in D_{M i}}\left(u^{(M)}, B u^{(M)}\right), \tag 2
> $$
> where
> $$
> D_{M i}=\left\{u \in D_M \mid\|u\|=1, \quad\left(u, u_j^{(M)}\right)=0 \text { for } j<i\right\},
> $$
> i.e. $E_0$ is the minimum of the expectation value of $B$ for $u^{(M)} \in D_M$. If the rayleigh ritz method does not converge to the ground state, then no sequence $u^{(M)} \in D_M$ exists, the expectation value of which converges to $E_0$. This, however, is a contradiction to the assumed

Here by Ritz eigenvalues $E_i^{(M)}$ it means the eingenvalues of the matrix $(B_M)_{ij}=(e_i,Be_j)$
where $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{span\{\left\{\Phi_m\right\}_{m=1}^M \}}$

I am not understanding how eq (1) is used in the proof.

Secondly  In the book [Relativistic Quantum Theory
of Atoms and Molecules](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-35069-1#:%7E:text=Relativistic%20quantum%20electrodynamics%2C%20which%20describes,with%20photons%20and%20other%20projectiles.) by I.P Grant at page 280 (theorem 5.9) it is said that eq $(2)$ comes from  the Weyl-Courant Theorem .

Let
$$
\theta\left(\mathcal{W}_n\right)=\min _{u \in \mathcal{W}_n^{\perp}} R(u) ;
$$

then
$$
t_n=\max _{\forall \mathcal{W}_n} \theta\left(\mathcal{W}_n\right)=\max _{\mathcal{W}_n \in \mathcal{S}_n} \min _{w \in \mathcal{W}_n^{\perp}} R(w),
$$
where $\mathcal{S}_n$ is the collection of all $n$-dimensional linear manifolds in $\mathcal{D}$.

I am not seeing how can eq(2) comes from the Weil  Courant theorem  because we have to take the maximun over all subspaces .

Finally I am not understanding why this expressions

*If the rayleigh ritz method does not converge to the ground state, then no sequence $u^{(M)} \in D_M$ exists, the expectation value of which converges to $E_0$. This, however, is a contradiction to the assumed*

is true?